# Is there a benefit to using <g:submitbutton> over <input> or <button>?

Tags: grails, gsp

For example, I think `g:form` escapes HTML input for you if a setting is set.
`g:textField` adds an `id` attribute with the same value as `name`.

How about `g:submitbutton`?

Answer (score 0):

I can think only in one difference: TagLibs. Let's say you want to create a default submit button for all your forms:

```
class FormTagLib {
  static namespace = "form"
  def submit = { attrs ->
    if(!attrs.id) {
      attrs.id = "myDefaultSubmitId"
    }

    out << g.submitButton(attrs)
  }
}
```

Here I'm setting a default id if none is provided. This is much more readable than creating an `<input>` in the tag.

And then you can use:

```
<form:submit value="Save" />
```

It will print the submit with the default id.